# Unexpected behavior with non-nested looping over multiple lists

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I want to produce a bunch of character vectors like

```
[1] "w2q5ea" "w2q5eb" "w2q5ec" "w2q5ed"
```

I have the following setup:

```
vars <- list(
  w1 = c("w2q5e*","w2q7e*"),
  w2 = c("w3q9*5","w3q13*5","w3q15*5"),
  w3 = c("w4q17*c","w4q16*c","w4q15*c"),
  w4 = c("w5q16*c","w5q14*c","w5q11*c"),
  w5 = c("w5q8*c"))

alphabet <- function(n) lapply(n,function(N) letters[1:N])

nletts <- list(
  w1 = list(unlist(alphabet(10)),unlist(alphabet(10))),
  w2 = list(unlist(alphabet(10)),unlist(alphabet(10)),unlist(alphabet(10))),
  w3 = list(unlist(alphabet(10)),unlist(alphabet(6)),unlist(alphabet(6))),
  w4 = list(unlist(alphabet(6)),unlist(alphabet(6)),unlist(alphabet(6))),
  w5 = list(unlist(alphabet(6))))
```

so that, e.g.,

```
> nletts[["w1"]]
[[1]]
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"

[[2]]
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

In order to hopefully produce something that looks like

```
[1] "w2q5ea" "w2q5eb" "w2q5ec" "w2q5ed"
[1] "w2q7ea" "w2q7eb" "w2q7ec" "w2q7ed"
```

And that's what I *thought* the following code would do:

```
temp <- list()
for( i in 1:2 ){
letts <- unlist(nletts[["w1"]][[i]])
for(l in seq_along(nletts)) for( v in vars[["w1"]] ) {
        temp <- append(temp,sub("\\*",letts[l],v))
    }
}
```

but apparently it's not right. I didn't print the result for the sake of making this post *somewhat* readable, but you can run what I have and see for yourself. For some reason it seems to be looping three times and not once. I suspect that something, somewhere, is vectorized in a way I'm missing, and for the life of me I can't figure out what it is. I've rewritten this code over and over for about four hours straight and I get the exact same problem each time. What's odd beyond all comprehension is that I can even replace `l` with an integer and step through it by hand to get the correct result.

Forget trying to do the original job I had in mind, which I could have finished three hours ago with copy & paste. I just want to understand what's going wrong. And the whole thing feels Hacky and Bad to begin with, so alternative suggestions are welcome.

---

Got it to work with

```
for( i in seq_along(vars[["w1"]]) ){

    print(sprintf(vars[["w1"]][i],letters[ nletts[["w1"]][i] ] ))

}
```

but I still want to know what went wrong above. I *think* what was happening is that I was really looping over each list element of `nletts` twice. I realize my loops were nested even though I didn't want them to be, so maybe the problem lies in there somewhere. Using the same index simultaneously clearly fixed the issue.

---

Better solution that doesn't require `append`:

```
whatever <- sapply(1:5, function(w){
    sapply( seq_along(vars[[w]]), function(i){
        sprintf(vars[[w]][i],letters[ 1:nletts[[w]][i] ] )
    },simplify=F)
},simplify=F)
```

But still no explanation for what went wrong.

Comment: The code isn't runnable. Variables `letts` and `gpavars` aren't defined. So you just want to replace the "*" with a single letter? Seems like you should just be using `paste()` with a prefix and suffix for each variable type.

Comment: `paste0` is your friend here.

Comment: `gpavars` should just be `vars`. fixed now.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I had been using `sprintf()` instead, but you're right: the way `paste()` is vectorized is much more transparent. I've been good friends with `paste0()` for a while now, but these characters also keep pretty bad company with `eval(parse())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trying this recipe:

```
R> vars <- c("w2q5e%s", "w5q8%sc")
R> lapply(vars, function (x) sprintf(x, letters))
[[1]]
 [1] "w2q5ea" "w2q5eb" "w2q5ec" "w2q5ed" "w2q5ee" "w2q5ef" "w2q5eg" "w2q5eh" "w2q5ei"
[10] "w2q5ej" "w2q5ek" "w2q5el" "w2q5em" "w2q5en" "w2q5eo" "w2q5ep" "w2q5eq" "w2q5er"
[19] "w2q5es" "w2q5et" "w2q5eu" "w2q5ev" "w2q5ew" "w2q5ex" "w2q5ey" "w2q5ez"

[[2]]
 [1] "w5q8ac" "w5q8bc" "w5q8cc" "w5q8dc" "w5q8ec" "w5q8fc" "w5q8gc" "w5q8hc" "w5q8ic"
[10] "w5q8jc" "w5q8kc" "w5q8lc" "w5q8mc" "w5q8nc" "w5q8oc" "w5q8pc" "w5q8qc" "w5q8rc"
[19] "w5q8sc" "w5q8tc" "w5q8uc" "w5q8vc" "w5q8wc" "w5q8xc" "w5q8yc" "w5q8zc"
```

Comment: This is the solution I should have come up with originally. Just first run `lapply(vars, sub("\\*","%s",x)`. +1 but I'm not going to mark this as an answer because I mainly want to understand why my code doesn't work.

Comment: Actually this doesn't solve the problem, because I want to use a different number of letters for each element of `vars`. So I still have to use a different subset of `letters` for every element of `vars`.

Comment: @ssdecontrol: I wanted to only show you the recipe. Having different sets of letters is easily handled with some application.

Comment: Well, replacing `letters` with `letters[1:n]` and looping over values of `n` gave me the same problem as before.

Comment: if you want to use a different number of letters, use `mapply` instead of `lapply`